# windows inputlanguage changed c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple program in Visual studio(windows application) and I need to know when the user is changing the keyboard language(I don't care what was the language or what it is now).

I have tried this code:

```
 private void MainForm_InputLanguageChanged(object sender, InputLanguageChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But it will only get the language change in the form when the form is active and focused! Example: I'll open Google chrome and change the language, this function will not be called.

I need to get the specific windows keyboard changed. Not the form inputlanguage changed..

it's very important for me I am breaking my head about a week for this so please help.

ty guys.

Comment: what have you tried? it sounds like you'll either have to implement a key listener and hope the user didn't change his default settings (sucks, wouldn't even try it), or try to find where windows stores that value, and track it ... sounds like a pain either way :)

Comment: i've heard about GetKeyboardLayoutName()... do u know this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far s I know, in Windows, input language is specific for process. So you get the InputLanguageChanged event for your application. If you want to be notified of language change globally, you should do it on your own. For example periodically check the active window and get keyboard layout using GetKeyboardLayout API function.