# What does changing the InputLanguage do?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm reviewing some code for a form, and see the following :

```
void SomeTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = GetLocalLanguage(DataModel.Country);
    SomeTextBox.ImeMode = ImeMode.On;
}
```

where `GetLocalLanguage()` goes through `InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages` and returns the country-specific one if applicable.

What is the purpose of this code? Why would we want to change the Input Language?

Comment: I think mostly in multithreading environment to ensure that the current thread has the correct InputLanguage. `Gets or sets the input language for the current thread.`

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage(v=vs.110).aspx) "An input language is a culture/keyboard layout pair that determines how the physical keys on a keyboard map or plot to characters in a language. The input language is based on a Windows input locale identifier, such as that returned by the Platform SDK function, GetKeyboardLayout. The input locale identifier is also called a handle to a keyboard layout (HKL) value." -- So it might be for supporting different keyboard layouts / languages.

Comment: (cont.) Does the application "expect" to be primarily used by 1 particular region? I'm not sure if the different InputLanguages might translate key codes differently. So that could tie into that, perhaps.

Comment: @sab669 We have different tabs for different countries/regions, and some tabs have this code setup on the Enter event of one of the TextBoxes. I am confused what this code is supposed to do... there is no multithreading in use here. I've updated my question with a sample block of code.

Comment: Tabs for different regions in the sense of "If it's a Customer from X country, fill out this tab" or "Someone in X country will use this tab for this record, then someone in Y country will open this record and fill out Y tab"? If the latter, then it might make sense to ensure the application is expecting the correct `InputLanguage` as different people from different regions modify it. Even for the former it might make sense, if the person entering the data is going to be entering characters from various languages.

Comment: @sab669 Users can be from all over the world, and can fill out the data on any number of the region-specific tabs. So it sounds like this is meant to be a way to handle non-english character input from different regions/keyboards? For example, the tab for China changes the InputLanguage so it can handle chinese character input that may not be handled correctly with the standard English language input?

Comment: That's what it sounds like to me. I couldn't find any concrete, real-world explanations for using / setting the `InputLanguage` on google though; just lots of questions about how to do it. Seems like you could try manually setting the `InputLanguage` to one value, enter a key and see what it's interpreted as, then change the language again and press the same key and see if it's a different value. Like using the `qwerty` layout versus `dvorak`, the same physical key on the keyboard might send a different key code to the software. Or be interpreted differently.

Comment: Thanks @sab669, if I get some time I'll do some tests like that and add the results here. I tried doing the same google searches and was getting the same results :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help a former co-worker ;)

Comment: @sab669 lol is that you Doug? I thought the username looked familiar.... I'm not at home (in NC for a few weeks) or I'd get on steam and chat :)

Comment: One of the uses is mentioned here -  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2007/04/29/changing-the-input-language-in-a-textbox-at-runtime.aspx . So perhaps in your case it automatically switches the keyboard as per the country

Comment: Thanks @Kapoor, the code there actually looks very similar to the code I'm looking at, so I'm guessing it originated based on that blog post :)

Comment: Here is an example of usage [How to change input-language in a windows forms application for a specific control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813818/how-to-change-input-language-in-a-windows-forms-application-for-a-specific-contr) - The OP wants to change input language automatically for some controls. Suppose you have a form which you need to enter data into some fields and some of them need English data and some of them need Persian data. Based on the code which I posted for that question, I created an Extender control which allow language be set at design-time.

Answer (score 0):

The input language element is simply the container for all the input language data. 
There is a sub item called "CurrentInputLanguage" which can be set and overridden from the Form's own language (defined in the resources).

In all my tests I have come to the conclusion that all changes are ignored.

- The keyboard input does not change. The keys are still identical.
- The formatting does not change. Numbers and parsed values do not change format.

I assume that this value should have been readonly.

Comment: This is not true. I must say. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594038/6201755 You must have some other issues. Can you please edit your post so it is clear that it was your special case?