# How to change input-language in a windows forms application for a specific control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want when the focus enters in a `TextBox`, change the language to an specific language (for example persian) and when the focus leaves `TextBox`, change the language to original language which was set before.

How to change input-language in a windows forms application when a specific control is focused?

Here is what I tried, but I don't want the user press any key, I want to change the language automatically.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Shift && e.Alt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("***language of keybord changed***");
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a hotkey for the language bar, you will not see it.  If you want to know about it then use the [InputLanguageChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.inputlanguagechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: You can change the input language programmatically using [`InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage(v=vs.110).aspx). 

It's enough to handle [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) and set it to desired language and handle [`Leave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) event and set it back to previous selected input language.

Answer (score 18):

You can change the input language programmatically using [`InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

It's enough to handle [`Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your control and set the `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage` to desired language and also handle [`Leave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of the control and set it back to previous selected input language.

In the below code, I set the input language to `Persian` when I enter `TextBox1` and set it to previous language when I leave the control:

```
InputLanguage original;
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    original = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
    var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR");
    var language = InputLanguage.FromCulture(culture);
    if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(language) >= 0)
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = language;
    else
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = original;
}
```

To test the example you should have `fa-IR` as input language installed on your OS, otherwise it will set the language to default input language. You can use another culture input-language which you know installed on your OS.

**Note:** If you extensively need such feature in your forms, as an idea you can create an [Extender Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms171836(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) component providing an `InputLanguage` property. This way you can set the property at design-time. That's the way that components like `ToolTip` or `HelpProvider` works.

Answer (score 3):

For people seeking similar solution for other languages that are available in many countries (e.g.: Arabic, there is "ar-SA","ar-EG" and many others) 
You can use this to get the correct language regardless of the country:

For WinForms:
VB:

```
originalInputLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage
Dim lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.OfType(Of InputLanguage).Where(Function(l) l.Culture.Name.StartsWith("ar")).FirstOrDefault()
        If lang IsNot Nothing Then InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang
```

C#:

```
originalInputLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
var lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.OfType<InputLanguage>().Where(l => l.Culture.Name.StartsWith("ar")).FirstOrDefault();
if (lang != null) {
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
}
```

For WPF:
VB:

```
Dim origianl As Globalization.CultureInfo //outside the event handler



// in the entered event handler:
origianl = InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage
Dim newLang = InputLanguageManager.
    Current.
    AvailableInputLanguages.
    OfType(Of Globalization.CultureInfo).
    Where(Function(i) i.Name.StartsWith("ar")).
    FirstOrDefault()
If newLang IsNot Nothing Then InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = newLang

//in the leave event handler:
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = original
```

C#:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo original; // outside the event handlers

// in the enter event handler:
original = InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage;
var newLang = InputLanguageManager.
    Current.
    AvailableInputLanguages.
    OfType<System.Globalization.CultureInfo>().
    Where(l => l.Name.StartsWith("ar")).
    FirstOrDefault();

if (newLang != null)
{
    InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = newLang;
}

// in the leave event handler:
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = original;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the system input language (so that every application will use the selected language) you can simply use [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=net-5.0) which simulates keyboard key presses:

```
SendKeys.Send("%+");
```

The string represents `Alt + Shift` which in Windows changes the input language by default.