# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser control is not obeying InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage property

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Using CefSharp 75.1.142, I have developed a C# Winforms application. It has a SplitContainer `splitContainer1` with the top panel having a ComboBox `combobox1` and with the bottom panel having `ChromiumWebBrowser` control.

I have Windows 7 with English and Greek keyboard layouts (default is English). During initialization, I change the app's input language to Greek and add ChromiumWebBrowser control like this:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-gr"));
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(browser);
```

However, while input language has changed for the application, the browser control continues to have the default input for my system, which is English.
If I click on the combobox, language bar of Windows 7 show Greek language, when I click on browser control, language bar shows English language.

How can I change input language for browser control, too?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35816248/3110834) *may* help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Could it have something to do with CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe or the UI thread of CefSharp? I'm changing input language for the whole app and yet CefSharp is ignoring it.

Comment: Yes, it might be the reason, apparently it uses different process.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using [IsBrowserInitializedChanged](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged.htm) event because according to the docs:

> Event called after the underlying CEF browser instance has been
>   created. It's important to note this event is fired on a CEF UI
>   thread, which by default is not the same as your application UI
>   thread.

So, I used:

```
browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
private void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-gr"));
}
```